# How can one link directly to a specific page of a PDF in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I'd like to provide a link to a PDF document in Google Drive like [documenturl]?page=4 and have that link jump to the specified page.

With a quick search, I was only able to find this unresolved forum question: [Link to a specific page in an uploaded .pdf](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/PnbUOnt5jok)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To link to a specific page in the PDF, use the following URL, but replace:

- `[ID]` with the document's ID (long string)
- `[pageNumber]` with the specific page's number

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[ID]#page=[pageNumber]
```

For example, if your `[ID]` is `Zg_D8hYY2p7ZO2_ZrS` and you want to link to `[pageNumber]` 10, your direct link would be:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=Zg_D8hYY2p7ZO2_ZrS#page=10
```

Google may rewrite the URL and there may be a delay while the page resolves.

Comment: Verified this works right now. However, the issue with this is that it opens up a view that disallows all of the other features that I would desire to continue to be available, such as clicking on the 3-dot menu and getting the original share link.  Usually, I need to have share links that I can keep in notes, and simply click upon them to route to the original PDF viewer page inside Drive for further full featured navigation, such as doing personal research and learning, etc.  Also, the "the files take ages to load" might be a non-starter for large PDF files.

Answer (score 22):

A work-around that I discovered for this is:

1. Create a comment on the PDF. Highlight the area that you want to be able to jump to (e.g. a heading on the page).
2. Click the 3-dot menu on the comment you just created, and choose "Link to this comment..."

You can send the displayed URL to someone and when they open it it will directly jump to that part of the PDF.

The solution by Christopher Harwood does not seem to work any more in the latest version of Google Drive.

Comment: For me, still worked as a charm: very useful. Please accept my admiration.

Comment: Create a comment in the page of .pdf you want the direct link of and copy the link of this comment. That's all!

Comment: problem with this solution is if you draw on the pdf and save it locally, the pdf will sync but erase the inserted comment. Which means you can't annotate the pdf.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work in a webview for both iOS and Android. Bummer..

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: This no longer works.**

Incomplete answer: Google Drive displays pages as images, so you can display specific pages by providing the direct image link.

```
https://DOMAIN/file/d/DRIVE_FILE_ID/image?pagenumber=NUMBER
```

Comment: Still not implemented it seems as the above answer does not work. I sent feedback in Google Drive. I encourage others to do the same and link back to this item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a comment inside the PDF with Acrobe Reader.
Then upload it in drive, click on the three buttons on top of the comment and select "link to". Only in this case it works.
If you add a comment directly in Google Drive, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Many PDF readers will honor open parameters in the link that leads to the PDF file, such as `page=5`. Use these parameters like this:

`https://www.example.org/somefile.pdf#page=5`

...or:

`https://www.example.org/somefile.pdf#page=5&comment=452fde0e-fd22`

To make this work with Google Drive, you need to obtain a `googleusercontent.com` link to the file. You can get it by downloading the file and noting the download location in `chrome://downloads/` or similar download list page. In most browsers, you can open the download list by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>. In the Mac Safari browser, use <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>.

See [PDF Open Parameters](https://www.evermap.com/AutoBookmark/Manual/OpenParameters.htm).